# Is this a correct way to analyze a graph? Warshall algorithm

Tags: java, graph, analysis

Here's an implementation of Warshall algorithm copied from this site 
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Floyd-Warshall_algorithm#Java

What I need is to analyze this algorithm.I already did but I want to make sure everything is correct.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) { //O(E)?
dist[weights[i][0] - 1][weights[i][1] - 1] = weights[i][2];}


    for (int i = 0; i < next.length; i++) {//O(v^2)
        for (int j = 0; j < next.length; j++)
            if (i != j)
                next[i][j] = j + 1;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < numVertices; k++)//O(v^3)
        for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++)
                if (dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] < dist[i][j]) {
                    dist[i][j] = dist[i][k] + dist[k][j];
                    next[i][j] = next[i][k];
                }

//Finally  takes O(v^3)
```

Comment: Floyd-Warshall is O(V^3).

Comment: Actually looks like homework. Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)